# NyroModal jQuery Plugin ignoring settings

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I'm trying to use the NyroModal jQuery plugin with the following code:

```
$('img').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.nmManual('pages/'+$(this).attr('id')+'.html', {
                        sizes: {
                            w: 1450,
                            h: 800,
                            initW: 2,
                            initH: 1
                        },
                        resizable: false,
                        closeOnEscape: false
                    });
                });
```

For some reason, the resizable and closeOnEscape work, but the 
sizes don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird because there's `resizable` option.

I tried using the sizes and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/hBxJn/2/

Comment: this is just weird, maybe I have the wrong version of Nyromodal?

Comment: maybe yes... I don't know I used the last from Github

Comment: tried using it as well... ultimately I changed the css without messing around with the sizes... shouldn't be a solution but it works :I

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.nmManual('http://jsfiddle.net/', {

    callbacks : {
        initFilters : function (nm) {
            nm.filters.push('link');
            nm.filters.push('iframe');
        },
        size:function(nm){
            nm.sizes.h = 550;
            nm.sizes.w = 550;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this Question:
To set the size of the nyroModal window you have to use:

```
        sizes: {
            minW: width,
            minH: height
        }
```

The other size parameters are all overwritten during the content load.

For an IFrame link the IFrame window size can only be changed in the nyroModal.css file :(

You can do that with jQuery:

```
$('.nyroModalCont,iframe').css('width', width + 'px');
$('.nyroModalCont,iframe').css('height', height + 'px');
```

Normally you should set both size options (nyroModal window + IFrame) for an IFrame to avoid double scrollbars...